# generate file preview for image/pdf/docx using jquery with remove option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  working with input type file so  my requirement is

1. Generate preview for any type of file like image/pdf/docx
2. selected file should appear with close symbol, so wehn click on that close symbol it file should removed

But the my code is generating preview for  pdf file only  ,not working for docx and I don't know how to remove file if click on close button and I am using iframe for preview any alternate way to achieve this kindly suggest me

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="filepreview" value="" id="filepreview" class="" data-errormsg="PhotoUploadErrorMsg">
<br>
  <iframe id="previewHolder" src="" height="70" width="70"></iframe>

  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" style="position: absolute;top:30px;opacity:1.2;">
  <span aria-hidden="true" style="color:black;">&times;</span>
</button>
<script>
    function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#previewHolder').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
$("#filepreview").change(function() {

  readURL(this);
});

</script>
```

Comment: you can't show non-browser files in the browser. to remove, set input.value=null;